# Connect two cloud run services on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, connection, google-cloud-run

I need to deploy two cloud run servicen on GCP, one is frontend and the other is backend so I wanna ask

1. is it possible to connect 2 services like this ones?
2. if its possible what is the best way of connecting those two services which will be able to communicate?

I searched through the internet didn't find a lot of useful info

Comment: What's the language of your frontend? Which user authentication mechanism do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider the official documentation :

[Securing Cloud Run services tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/secure-services)

> This tutorial walks through how to create a secure two-service
> application running on Cloud Run. This application is a Markdown
> editor which includes a public "frontend" service which anyone can use
> to compose markdown text, and a private "backend" service which
> renders Markdown text to HTML.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you i'm not going to go into details. but i will give you a quick overview of the workflow.
Assuming you don't have the code in source control and this is an already built docker containers.

1. you want to load the docker image via gcloud by using
   docker load to load the docker .tar image.
2. next you will tag that image.
3. push the image to container registry
4. navigate to cloud web-console click create service or you can run gcloud run image on the cli.
5. if you need a db its much better to use the cloud sql assuming its postgresql. you want to create one beforehand in the same region.
6. during deployment you can click connection tab and attach your db instance set the container port to your listening port.
   don't for get to like if it helps!